# CSS: Poner un button debajo de otro

Tags: css

¿Como se puede poner un button debajo de otro? Podría ponerlos dentro de divs y tocar los divs, pero me gustaría hacerlo sin.

```css
.btn-danger{
  display:flex;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<form method="POST" action="{{route('admin.projects.destroy',$project->id)}}" onsubmit="return ConfirmarBorrarProyecto()">
  <a href="{{ route('admin.project.edit', $project->id)}}" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" id="margindata">Edit</a> 
  <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" id="margindata">
  <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{Session::token()}}">
</form>
```

Comment: No se a que te refieres, podrias poner cada boton dentro de un div con la class "input-field col s12 m12 12" o simplemente un `<br>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Agrega `display: block !important;`

```css
.btn-danger{
  display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<form method="POST" action="{{route('admin.projects.destroy',$project->id)}}" onsubmit="return ConfirmarBorrarProyecto()">
  <a href="{{ route('admin.project.edit', $project->id)}}" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" id="margindata">Edit</a> 
  <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" id="margindata">
  <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{Session::token()}}">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

No hay que manipular ningún `CSS` con los [css-helpers de Bootsrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#buttons-sizes) lo puedes conseguir con:

- `btn-block`

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<form method="POST" action="" onsubmit="return ConfirmarBorrarProyecto()">
  <a href="" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" id="margindata">Edit</a> 
  <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm btn-block" id="margindata">
  <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="">
</form>
```

Comment: ¿Y si no quieres ese cacho boton? Solo el mismo tamaño de antes pero debajo.

Comment: @GDP - Simple... Ya que el OP usa Bootstrap debería usar el sistema de grid

Comment: gracias. No suelo usar Bootstrap y no me manejo del todo. Apunto, probablemente lo termine necesitando alguna vez :)

Answer (score 0):

Depende de que manera te guste mas.

---

**margin-right:100%;**

```css
.btn-danger{
   margin-right:100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<form method="POST" action="{{route('admin.projects.destroy',$project->id)}}" onsubmit="return ConfirmarBorrarProyecto()">
  <a href="{{ route('admin.project.edit', $project->id)}}" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" id="margindata">Edit</a> 
  <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" id="margindata">
  <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{Session::token()}}">
</form>
```

---

**position:relative;**

```css
    .btn-danger{
      position:relative;
      top:30px;
      left:-47px;
    }
```

```html
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <form method="POST" action="{{route('admin.projects.destroy',$project->id)}}" onsubmit="return ConfirmarBorrarProyecto()">
      <a href="{{ route('admin.project.edit', $project->id)}}" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" id="margindata">Edit</a> 
      <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" id="margindata">
      <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{Session::token()}}">
    </form>
```

---

**display: block**
*@Pablo version*

```css
.btn-danger{
  display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <form method="POST" action="{{route('admin.projects.destroy',$project->id)}}" onsubmit="return ConfirmarBorrarProyecto()">
          <a href="{{ route('admin.project.edit', $project->id)}}" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" id="margindata">Edit</a> 
          <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" id="margindata">
          <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{Session::token()}}">
        </form>
```

Y mas formas seguro existen, dependerá siempre de donde y como quieras presentarlos, contenedor o elementos adyacentes.

Comment: Las dos primeras opciones que pones no son útiles... No puedes darle un margen del 100% a no ser que quieras una web con solo dos botones. Tampoco puedes andar colocando los botones pixel a pixel en una posicion relativa, va a depender mucho del tamaño y de los objetos de alrededor.
La única que me parece valida es la última y las estas copiando de la otra respuesta XD

Comment: Creo que solo ha preguntado la manera de poner un boton debajo de otro mediante css, le he ofrecido varias alternativas con css, en el caso de que le valga ninguna por lo menos sabrá que esas opciones existen, ademas, al final dejo claro que siempre dependerá del como y donde quiera presentarlo, de haber supuesto otro ejemplo mas elaborado me hubiese adaptado a lo que ha se me presentase, mas opciones o metodos nunca vienen mal, creo yo,